# General Formula for electric flux

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I've noticed that most of Physics 2 courses highlight the fact that the surface is closed before giving the electric flux formula. Is the following formula only valid for closed surfaces? If yes, are there any general formulas (for both opened and close surfaces).

Note: I read on previous posts that one can use symmmetry to deduce the flux in open surfaces (calculate the flux for a cube before dividing it by 6 to obtain the flux for a square)

Comment: *Is the following formula only valid for closed surfaces?* You didn’t include the formula.

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) if you’d like to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is no reason that one cannot calculate the flux through non-closed surfaces. One uses the same methods, i.e. surface integrals:
$$\text{flux}=\int_{S}\vec F\cdot d\vec A,$$
where $S$ is the surface of integration on which $d\vec A$ is defined. The reason elementary texts emphasize closed surfaces is that they are so useful in applying Gauss' law, which *does* require closed surfaces.